# Write an application that will display the output below using 2 for loops in PHP

Tags: php

1

12

123

1234

12345

123456

1234567

12345678

123456789

Comment: Voting to close, since this smells very strongly of homework.

Comment: By the way: You can also do this with just one `for` loop.

Comment: You can even do it without a single loop :)

Comment: @Gumbo: heck, you don't _need_ a loop at all!

Comment: But not for an arbitrary number. There always is some kind of repetition.

Comment: @Gumbo: You could circumwent the loop using array functions which accept callbacks ;) Internally, this would still loop, but you don't write the loop in PHP explicitly ;)

Comment: @everyone, so a simple homework question will not be answered on SO ? I thought SO [favors this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/homework-on-stackoverflow/10825#10825).

Comment: @nikic: Yes. You could also use recursion and a buffer. But it’s still some kind of repetition.

Comment: @shamittomar: Well, from the first answer: "Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first." And if you tell me that this user has put serious effort in solving the problem, then, well, I obviously missed a new breakout of stupidity. And from this answer, too: "Ask about specific problems with your existing implementation." I don't see any code in this question. Obviously the OP want's someone else to do his work and I am not going to support this!

Comment: @nikic: OK, going back to reddit.

Comment: @shamittomar: Homework questions are fine as long as they are not just the homework question but a question about the homework (see also [tvanfosson’s comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/homework-on-stackoverflow/10825#comment-65884)).

Comment: @Gumbo, yes I agree completely with you and tvanfosson. I just remember when I was a 11 year old kid learning C. Back then, there was no Internet and I was stuck on very similar *numerical pyramid* making problems for days (sometimes weeks). The school did not give programming-classes, I was learning programming of my own. I wish I had someone to help me out. Now when I see such problems, I remember my days and my heart craves out to help students :-(

Comment: @shamittomar: I do know, that it is hard to learn programming. And I try to help and answer questions wherever I can. But this particular case doesn't show any signs of the OP having tried to solve the problem. If he really were interested in solving this, he would have given some code and asked why it doesn't work and not simply written the output of the program he wants to have. It's the difference between a question out of interest (even if it originally was a homework) and a question only to save him the time thinking about his homework.

Comment: @shamittomar, homework questions are fine when they have posted the supporting code that they tried. Something like this, they might as well just give you the homework and say, "have it done for me by tonight oh and I did not even try this at all by myself."

Comment: @premiso, @nikic, @Gumbo: Thanks for clearing that up. Next time, instead of posting an answer, I will vote for closing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that so hard?

```
<?php

for($i=1;$i<10;$i++)
{
    for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++)
        echo $j;
    echo '<br/>';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
  for ($j = 1; $j <= $i; $j++) {
    echo $j;
  }
  echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: +1 Even though this isn't an ingenious answer it is in no way worse than shamittomar's (and even better, because it respects coding standards!). So I don't see why people vote for his answer and not for this one...

Comment: Like question, like answer :D